# What to do first: effects or montage?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I have to make a five-minute video for a school project. The video includes a few interviews where I want to have their name and job description slide in, and blur the background to prevent distractions. I was planning to do these edits in AE and make a montage of the interviews in Premiere Pro. So in what order do you recommend to do these activities? Both options have their pros and cons:

- If I montage it first, AE has to render the whole video again, and I suppose that's not necessary for the parts where I'm not going to use masks and stuff.
- If I edit it first, I'm probably going to apply masks at fragments that I'm not going to use, that's also quite time-consuming.

So which method do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to first edit your video completely in Premiere Pro and then use the dynamic-link feature. If you do it the other way round, you won't know exactly what footage will be used and on which clips to apply the effects. If you've already edited your clips and put them into a timeline you know how your final film will look and you're able to integrate the effects much better into your film.

For the dynamic-link workflow, create a new timeline in Premiere Pro and do all of your editing (what you called montaging).
After you've done with your final edit, you can bring the clips into After Effects to do the effects. Right-click on the clip you want to edit and select "*replace with After Effects composition*". Then this single clip will be automatically opened in After Effects and you can apply your effects. The clip in your Premiere timeline will be automatically replaced with the AE composition and you still are able to change your edit later and change stuff in your timeline. Then after you've done all the effects you need render the Premiere Pro timeline and you have your finished film.

Answer (score 0):

I second. Your approach to this should be focused on the story, the graphics are a finishing touch. Cut up your bytes, and condense them down. Cut out all of the ums, ahhs, reconstruct bytes to make them more concise, to pack as much information- the good stuff- into as tight a timeframe as possible.

Now you have a basic string out of interviews ready to work with.

Lay down music. You'll want some breathers. Where the bytes break to music (typically during chorus) and you montage b-roll shots/graphics/supporting visuals.

Construct where where these breathers will be. Create the stringout using the music... if it's a 5 minute piece, most likely 2-3 songs. Make sure you splice them, and pay them off. They need to end. Get your song edits cut, and place markers where your breathers will go, where interviews will go.

Now start placing the interview bytes. Focus on structure and story. That's what really matters. Period.

Next, lay in b-roll. Cover any interview jumpcuts where edits were made, and fill in the breathers. Pay Off and Open each song with graphics and strong visuals.

Lastly, you can take your project output into AE, and create your lower thirds. Graphics.

If you don't want to use the Dynamic Link Flow approach listed above- which does work, but I prefer hard assets rendered to disk, you can build your graphics with your video output from premiere. Then render out just the graphic sections and disabling the video track (so theres no background). Render out as Quicktime Codec Animation 100 Q with Alpha RGB+Alpha.

These files will be uncompressed 100% quality renders of your graphics, and you can drop them back into premiere and re-render a final output.

For archive:  Easiest to just save the entire project to 2 copies on disk, but if you want to archive as a "lay to tape" method, just make sure you render the program clean (no graphics), program dirty (with graphics), then mix minuses, one only music, one only bytes, one only sfx, one only music no mix, etc.

Saving to disk, far easier.